# respond_to format.json doesn't work inside of rescue_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code to handle ActiveRecord:RecordNotFound exceptions in my ApplicationController

```
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { message: 'Unable to find record' }, status: 404 }
      format.html { render 'errors/404' , status: 404 }
    end
    true
  end
```

However when receiving a JSON request "Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*" it insists on executing the `format.html` block. If I remove the `format.html` block it throws an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` exception. At this point I'm stuck.